# What is an efficient method for retrieving a column from an array?

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays

An example in any language would help, though in the end I am going to be using either Ruby or JavaScript/CoffeeScript.

I have an array of pixel values. For example, I have an array that represents the pixels of a 5x5 image.

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

The image would be like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5
```

I already have a way of getting rows. But I want a way to also retrieve a column for an index.

Let's say I had a method in Ruby:

```
class Array
  def column(index)
    ...
  end
end
```

I would like the following results:

```
image.column(0) #=> [1,6,1,6,1]
image.column(3) #=> [4,9,4,9,4]
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to everyone who provided their assistance.  Here is what I went with:

```
def column index
  output = []
  i = 0
  while i < @height
    output << pixel(index + (i * @width))
    i += 1
  end
  output
end
```

Pixel is another method I have that returns an averaged value from an array of RGBA values, given an index.

The reason this suffices is that I can safely assume that every row/column in the image is the correct size.  I also wanted to keep the process fairly simplistic as I am likely to make this a CoffeeScript application that will use typed clamped arrays(for performance reasons and the fact that canvas data is a Uint8ClampedArray), in which case the value of output would be a Uint8ClampedArray and I'd be using the index instead of push, since Uint8ClampedArray doesn't/can't support push/pop/shift/unshift.

Comment: Implementation questions are best asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's an implementation issue, so it should go to SO.  Answers to your question will (should) be primarily code based.  ie. take the size of each row and use that to increment the index value to retrieve the column.  So if you want the the 3rd column, you'll fetch myArray[2+row_size*0], myArray[2+row_size*1], myArray[2+row_size*2], etc...

Comment: the non-math way is to just iterate from rowSize to length stepping rowSize, collecting the current each time.

Comment: I see your point GlenH7.  Thanks for migrating the question to SO.

Also, I realize that this question is pretty basic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the other answers will work for an image that is exactly 5x5 as your question specifies but in the case where this is not implicitly true I would build a class for this such as:

```
class ImageMap
  attr_reader :image
  def initialize(image,columns=nil)
    @image = image.each_slice(columns ||= Math.sqrt(image.size)).to_a 
  end
  def columns
    @image.first.size
  end
  def rows
    @image.size
  end
  def column(n)
    @image.map{|a| a[n]}
  end
  def row(n)
    [@image[n]].concat([nil] * columns).take(columns).flatten
  end
  def cell(column,row)
    column(column)[row]
  end
  def print
    @image.each {|a| puts a.join}
  end
end
```

This will handle all images and allows you to also set the number of expected columns as well. If no column expectation is made then it tries to make it square.

**Square**

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
im = ImageMap.new(image)
im.column(0)
#=> [1, 6, 1, 6, 1]
im.column(3)
#=> [4, 9, 4, 9, 4]
im.row(0)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
im.cell(4,2)
#=> 5
```

**Non Square**

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]
im = ImageMap.new(image,4)
im.column(0)
#=> [1, 5, 9, 3, 7, 1, 5]
im.columns
#=> 4
im.rows
#=> 7
```

Obviously this could use some handling for out of bounds values but you should be able to deal with that. Example with non-existent rows/columns:

```
im.column(7)
#=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
im.row(7)
#=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
im.cell(7,2)
#=> nil
```

Also note if it is not square it will still function e.g.

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,4] # added a 4
im = ImageMap.new(image)
im.column(0)
#=> [1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 4]
im.column(1)
#=> [2, 7, 2, 7, 2, nil]
im.image
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4]]
```

**Update based on OP current solution**
This method should preform the same function and is a bit more rubyesque

```
def column index
  (0...@height).map { |i| pixel(index + (i * @width)) }
end
```

Comment: That the column size equals the row size is your own assumption, which may not be true.

Comment: @sawa fixed my class to allow for custom column size. Rows will be determined by columns. Also fixed row to be a proper row in the event of uneven or non-existent.

Comment: Very detailed answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @Ravenstine thank you. I have also updated my answer with a method that will return the same as your solution but is a bit more idiomatic ruby.

Answer (score 3):

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5]

def column(image, n, row_length)
  (n..image.length).step(row_length).map{|i| image[i]}
end

column(image, 3, 5) # => [4, 9, 4, 9, 4]
```

Comment: The OP explicitly mentioned that they want the method to be defined on the `Array` class.

Comment: @sawa the OP simply stated *Let's say...*. I read this as I could implement this way but an open to suggestion. So I am inclined to agree with Sergio on this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the Array class, in fact I wouldn't even implement it that way.  It was just for example.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than creating new methods in the class `Array`, you might consider creating a separate class. I have assumed the size of `image` is a multiple of a number of rows--considering the example and that we are talking pixels--but the code obviously could be changed if that assumption were dropped.

Thanks to @SergioTulentsev and @engineersmnky for their suggestions (see comments), which I've implemented.

**Code**

```
class Array2D
  def initialize(arr, ncols)
    raise ArgumentError, "ncols must be positive" if ncols < 1
    raise ArgumentError,
      "arr.size must a multiple of ncols" unless (arr.size % ncols).zero?
    @arr   = arr
    @ncols = ncols
    @nrows = arr.size/ncols
  end

  def [](r,c)           @arr[r*@ncols+c]               end
  def row(r)            @arr[r*@ncols, @ncols]         end
  def rows_at(*indices) indices.map { |i| row(i) }     end
  def col(c)            @nrows.times.map { |r,a| self[r,c] } end
  def cols_at(*indices) indices.map { |i,a| col(i) }   end
  def array()           rows_at(*0...@nrows)           end
  def transpose()       cols_at(*0..@ncols)            end
  alias :to_s :array
end

Array2D.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:[], :row, :rows_at, :col, :cols_at, :array, :transpose, :to_s]
```

Note that `self` is required in `self[r,c]` in the method `col`. Without `self`, `[1,2]` returns an array.

**Example**

```
image = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,10,21,22,23,24,25]

image2D = Array2D.new(image, 5)

image2D.array
  #=> [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
  #    [ 6,  7,  8,  9,  0],
  #    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  #    [16, 17, 18, 19, 10],
  #    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
image2D[1,3]
  #=> 9 
image2D.row(1)
  #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 0] 
image2D.rows_at(1,3)
  #=> [[6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [16, 17, 18, 19, 10]]
image2D.col(1)
  #=> [2, 7, 12, 17, 22] 
image2D.cols_at(1,3)
  #=> [[2, 7, 12, 17, 22],
  #    [4, 9, 14, 19, 24]]
image2D.transpose
  #=> [[1, 6, 11, 16, 21],
  #    [2, 7, 12, 17, 22],
  #    [3, 8, 13, 18, 23],
  #    [4, 9, 14, 19, 24],
  #    [5, 0, 15, 10, 25]]
```

Comment: Subclassing classes like Hash and Array is almost always bad. And here's is definitely very bad, because you're redefining parent API (`[]`, for example), thus violating LSP. There are other sins too, but this one is enough :)

Comment: Egad, @Sergio, what was I thinking??  I removed `< Array` and promise to never do that again. (I guess I had `Array` on the brain.)

Comment: hehe.  http://bossip.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/robert-de-niro-bringing-his-angry-eyes-to-cannes-2011.jpg?w=535

Comment: As Always nice solution. Although `each_with_object([])` seems like it would be more concise by using `map` e.g. `def rows_at(*indices) indices.map{ |i| row(i) } end`

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks smnky.  I seem to often forget about `map` in situations like this one. After reading your answer I also changed the argument `nrows` to `ncols`, which seems more sensible.

Answer (score 1):

```
def column(index)
    (0...5).map{|i|image[i*5+index]}
end
```

Comment: If you are using `image` that way, then what is the point of defining the method on `Array` class?

Comment: The method would be more robust if `5` were an argument.